# let variable reassigned but stay undefined (socket.io, node.js, react)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I am implementing a real time chat app using react and node but struggling with sending messages to the server. Below is my Chat component where socket connection with the server starts.

The problem is when I hit the send button, `sendMsg` runs and gives me an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined`. `socket` is assigned the return values of `socketIOClient(ENDPOINT)`inside useEffect but seems to stay undefined at the time of hitting the send button. I guess

Can someone please help me fix this?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import Loading from './Loading';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { Container, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Fragment } from 'react';
import queryString from 'query-string';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:4001";

const Chat = ({location}) =>{

  const [msgList, setMsgList] = useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = useState(null);

  let socket;

  useEffect(()=>{
    const {name} = queryString.parse(location.search);
    setName(name)

      socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);
      socket.emit("setName", name)

    if(socket){
      socket.on("greeting", (data)=>{
      setMsgList(msgList => [...msgList, {type: "server", msg:data}]);
      console.log(msgList)
    })
  }

    return()=>{
      if(socket){
        socket.disconnect();
      }
    }

  },[location.search, name])


  const sendMsg = (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(socket)
    socket.emit("message", {msg: event.target.message.value})

  }


  return (
    <Fragment>
    <Container > 
      <Box maxWidth="600px" height="100vh" marginX="auto" marginY="0" textAlign="center" position="relative">
        <Box paddingY="15px">
          <Typography variant="h4">Let's Chat!</ Typography>
        </Box>
        <Box>
          {msgList.map((msgObj, index)=>{
            return <p key={index + 1}>{msgObj.type}: {msgObj.msg}</p>
          })}
        </Box> 
        <Box position="absolute" bottom="0" left="0"width="100%" zIndex="10">
          <form autoComplete="off" onSubmit={sendMsg}>
            <TextField name="message" label="say something" variant="outlined" fullWidth />
            <Button type="submit" color="secondary" fullWidth variant="contained">Send</Button>
        </form>
        </Box>
      </Box>


    </Container>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default Chat;
```

Comment: `socket` is redeclared without value each render cycle, so OFC it is undefined. Move the declaration *outside* the component, or use a react ref to store the socket value and persist it through rerenders.

Comment: ahhh that's why... I moved it outside the component and it worked. thanks so much for your help, I learned an important lesson.